# How to prevent docker apache from creating http folder on docker-compose up

Tags: docker, apache

I have this docker-compose file:

```
version: "3.2"

services:
  apache:

    build:
      context: './docker/apache/'

    ports:
      - "80"

    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/
      
    container_name:
      apache
```

Dokerfile only contais this:

```
FROM php:7.3-apache

# i tried with this but it doesn't work
RUN rmdir /var/www/html
```

each time I try to up the containers it creates the html folder,
how I could stop it or force it to create another named public_html?

Comment: why you want to remove `/var/www/html` inside the container, I think its created by default.

Comment: on production we use the ```/var/www/public_html``` folder as a directory root,
and the ```/var/www/html```  it has no porpuse on the project

Comment: The `volumes:` are replacing `/var/www` in the container with the contents of the current directory from the host; if the host has an `html` directory that will be visible inside the container, and the Dockerfile is completely ignored here.  You may want to `COPY` content into your image instead of using `volumes:` to mount host content in the container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :
`docker-compose.yaml`

```
version: "3.2"

services:
  apache:

    build:
      context: './docker/apache/'

    ports:
      - "80"
      
    container_name:
      apache
```

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM php:7.3-apache

WORKDIR /var/www/public_html
COPY index.php .
COPY app/ /var/www
```

Edited after @david-maze comment.

You better to put your views wanted to be in `public_html` in a folder and just mount it other than all things in the current folder.As an example

```
volumes:
      - views/:/var/www/public_html
```

Comment: if we go this way we can't access the ```/var/www``` and we need to, thank you anywa

Comment: (`WORKDIR` will create the directory if it doesn't exist; you don't need to `RUN mkdir` manually.)

Comment: @DavidMaze the thing is that i have the index.php file on the ```/var/www/public_html/index.php```

and the controllers are on ```/var/www/app/Http/Controllers```,
making it this way I can't access the controllers and i have to store all my php code inside ```public_html```

Comment: @VasylYovdiy added a work around, removed volumes from `docker-compose` and added individual copy to your files.